# how to get order shipment comments in MG2 using DI ( dependecency injection)

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

I can obtain shipment object from Observer object as follows.

```
$shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();
```

But from here how can I get shipment comments? I mean the comment added in Shipment admin page.

Thank you,

Comment: Which event you are using ? please provide more details into your question so people can answer your question

Comment: Hi, Keyur, I'm using 'sales_order_shipment_save_after' event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my full code which gets shipment comment from observer

```
$shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();

$shipment_comment = $shipment->getCommentsCollection()
                    ->getFirstItem()
                    ->getComment();
```

Thank you Fabian.

Answer (score 3):

If you already have a shipment instance, you can use:

```
$shipment->getCommentsCollection();
```

There is no need to inject further dependencies.

Comment: Hi Fabian, with this collection how I can get last comment which is added at 'sales_order_shipment_save_after' event ? 
Thank you,

Comment: The comment collection is sorted by creation date, descending. So you can use `$shipment->getCommentsCollection()->getFirstItem()`

Comment: This solved my problem.

$shipment_comment = $shipment->getCommentsCollection()
->getFirstItem()
->getComment();

Thank you Fabian